# How do I refer to a socket as a class variable that I can use later?

Tags: python, sockets, oop, python-sockets

In my case I have a texting app that has a receiver class that accepts incoming connections, and it has a pyqt signal connected to the main app class that will add messages to the screen upon being received. I want to be able to have two of these running and connect to eachother on different ports and send messages back and forth. This also means I want it to be able to run and listen for connections before itself connecting back.

I thought I'd create a connecter class, with the socket as a class variable, and then later instantiate that within the main app and link the send button pyqt signal to a send function that sends over that socket. It doesn't seem to like this. I get the error "socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as self.s" invalid syntax.

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import socket
import numpy as np
from collections import deque, namedtuple
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
inPORT = int(input('Input port to receive from: '))
outPORT = int(input('Input port to send to: '))

class Receiver(QThread):    
    received = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        # self.outPORT = input('Input port to connect to: ')

        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.bind((HOST, inPORT))
            s.listen()
            print('Listening...')

            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                print('Connected by', addr)
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    self.received.emit(data)

class Connecter():
    def __init__(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as self.c
        self.c.connect((HOST, outPORT))

class ChatApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_area = QTextEdit()
        self.text_area.setReadOnly(True)
        self.message_line = QLineEdit()
        self.message_line.setFocus()
        self.button = QPushButton('Send')

        outerLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        outerLayout.addWidget(self.text_area)
        bottomLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        bottomLayout.addWidget(self.message_line)
        bottomLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        outerLayout.addLayout(bottomLayout)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(outerLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Chat App")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('ChatIcon.png'))
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.name = 'frd'

        receiver = Receiver()
        receiver.received.connect(self.addMessages)
        self.threads = [receiver]

        connecter = Connecter()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.sendMessage)
        self.message_line.returnPressed.connect(self.sendMessage)

        receiver.start()

    # def askName(self):
    #     name, ask = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'input dialog', 'Enter username: ')
    #     return name

    def sendMessage(self):
        message = self.message_line.text()
        connecter.c.sendall(message)
      
            # headerArr = np.array([len(message)], dtype=np.uint16)
            # header = headerArr.tobytes

    def addMessages(self, message):
        self.text_area.append(message.decode('utf-8'))


app = QApplication([])
myApp = ChatApp()
myApp.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Post your code, in its entirety

Comment: Why are you trying to use ``with`` for this? It's purpose for sockets is to automatically *close* the resource at the end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

The point of `with` is it creates something, then closes it again after the code inside the `with` is done. That doesn't apply here. It's not what you want the computer to do.

You can assign the socket to the variable like so:

```
self.c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

and when you are done with the socket, close it like so:

```
self.c.close()
```

Comment: "with always creates a local variable. You can't use with." Actually, one can – [``with`` assigns to a regular ``target``](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), including an ``attributeref``. Not that it would be sensible in this case…